Alternate epsilon-delta proof of the limit of the reciprocal function
I'm trying to prove the following using the epsilon-delta method:
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{x} = 1$$
Prior to reading the fantastic answer by @Clarinetist in this question, I tried writing the proof myself. My approach begins similarly to the aforementioned response, but I wanted to verify the final details of it. Anyway, here it is:
$$\left|\frac{1}{x} - 1\right| = \left|\frac{1-x}{x}\right| = \left|\frac{x-1}{x}\right|$$
$$ = \frac{|x - 1|}{|x|}$$
Now, if $|x - 1| < |x|\epsilon$, we'll be done.
$$|x - 1| < |x|\epsilon\implies |x| - |1| < |x|\epsilon$$
$$|x| - |x|\epsilon < 1\implies |x|(1-\epsilon) < 1$$
$$|x| < \frac{1}{1-\epsilon}$$
Now:
$$|x - 1| < \frac{1}{1-\epsilon} - 1\implies |x| - |1| < \frac{1}{1-\epsilon} - 1\implies |x| < \frac{1}{1-\epsilon}$$
Therefore, $\delta = \frac{1}{1-\epsilon} - 1$

You have implications in the wrong direction.  $|x| <\frac 1 {1-\epsilon}$ does not yield $|x-1|<|x| \epsilon$.

@geetha290krm why not? I would assume that each step is reversible. That is, $|x| < \frac{1}{1-\epsilon}\implies |x|(1 - \epsilon) < 1\implies |x| - |x|\epsilon < 1$ and so on. Could you point out which specific step fails to obey this assumption?

$|x|-|x|\epsilon <1$ does not imply that $|x-1|<|x|\epsilon$. [Take, for example, $x=0$].

@geetha290krm ah my bad. Thanks for the clarification
